# How do I save printer settings as a text file

Tags: windows, operating-system, printers, thermal-printer

In windows is there a way, an app, a Windows System Call, a powershell script to save all printer settings as a text file.

I just want the information, I dont need to be able to reload it again into a printer.

I have a very finicity printer and want to make sure it always has the correct settings.  I would like to be able to compare 2 text files of settings on 2 differnt dates.

Comment: This may have been answers on another StackExchange site: https://superuser.com/questions/135393/list-printers-from-command-line-to-text-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should look here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/get-printerproperty?view=win10-ps

you can list the printers and their properties using powershell like so:

```
$printers = get-printer *
foreach ($printer in $printers)
{
    get-printerproperty -printerName $printer.name| Out-File -FilePath .\filename.txt -Append
}
```

get the print configuration:

```
$Printers = Get-Printer *
Foreach ($Printer in $Printers){
Get-PrintConfiguration -PrinterName $Printer.name | Out-File .\filename.txt -Append 
}
```

each of the methods has a set method accordingly

to get the drivers installed on your pc:

```
Get-PrinterDriver -Name * | Out-File .\filename.txt -Append
```

for the ports:

```
Get-PrinterPort | Out-File .\filename.txt -Append
```

if you use all of them together i belive you will get the desired affect

or using cmd you have anothr option to use (i find it less readable):
wmic printer list >> 1.txt